# How can I implement file system cache that is shared across instances(containers) of the same app on an Azure Web App Serice?

Tags: python, azure, flask, caching, azure-web-app-service

I'm new to app developments and I'm working on improving the response time of my app. I currently have implemented caching with the Flask-Cashing module. My app is being hosted in Azure App Service as a container in Linux if I'm not mistaken. I want to know how I can share a cache between instances or containers in my scenario. I was thinking about a filesystem cache but if anyone has suggestions I'm more than happy to listen.

Answer (score 0):

This usually calls for a distributed cache like `redis`, which you can provision using the [Azure Cache for Redis](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-overview) service. This should be more efficient in general for most use cases.

If you would still like to use the filesystem cache, you could consider [mounting an Azure File Share to your App Service Instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/configure-connect-to-azure-storage?tabs=portal&pivots=container-linux).